# Defining a deeply nested object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function that flattens an array of objects that might be deeply nested. The implementation works, but I'm having trouble to define the right types for it.

The data that should be passed in as an argument should be an array of objects and each of the objects can in turn have an array of similar objects as a property, which in turn can have more items, and so on:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    items: [
      { name: 'Bar' },
      { name: 'Baz',
        items: [
          {name: 'Foobarbaz'},
          ...
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

What I would expect to work is the following:

```
export const flattenBy = <
    NestingProp extends string,
    Item extends {
        [nestedItems in NestingProp]?: Item[];
    }
>(
    items: Item[] = [],
    prop: NestingProp
): Item[] =>
    items?.reduce(
        (acc, item) => [...acc, item, ...flattenBy(item[prop], prop)],
        [] as Item[]
    );
```

But unfortunately this does not work even with the most basic sample data. When passing `[{name: 'foo'}]` it seems as though the first level must always have items as TS complains:

```
TS2322: Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ items: { name: string; }[] | undefined; }'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type '{ items: { name: string; }[] | undefined; }'.
```

And when passing `[{name: 'foo', items: [{name: 'bar'}]}]` it seems as though having a `items` property is required:

```
TS2741: Property 'items' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type '{ name: string; items: { name: string; }[]; }'.
```

Now I'm confused, since

1. `Item` extends the nested object structure, so shouldn't any other property (such as `name`) be valid as well?
2. Why is `items` required, even though it is marked as optional?

I feel I am missing something big and would greatly appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance!

Edit: Here is a [link to a TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wGYBsCGMbDIBCAnnALxwA8AUHPXAHLDoCWyA5gApQRhygCyACao46KOw4AaOgwCSBALYCQQ0XADechgwDayFgWGLgSseyZGpPPgF0A-AC44ppXrsBuHXAC+NAD4ACh9WZVQXNw8KOA9ZXTBeMBdmNk5bMBoASkjlaPIA0PCHADooYGEAVwRgEN1dIJwEBGk4MLMsigDYkt6mlrblVt6S7DwhUiD290T7VtmwLLt4+vponDEoux8s7xoaJDR4FGAAGWAAN2AsGL1NZBwlYBcAcgwICBffbbH8QkmTucrlhWi9pqgXll9od0HAYAB3CBA65iSh3B5PV7vT6tcEudGPZ5wF4AIxwUC+dm+NF+ExIQQRSMuKNB4MhQA). I've also ditched the extra `NestingObject` type.

Comment: It's better if you can share your `flattenBy` implementation, it can directly affect how it can be typed.

Comment: Will `Item extends NestedItem<NestingProp> | Omit<NestedItem<NestingProp>, NestingProp` work for you?

Comment: @yqlim Yes, you're right. I've updated my question to include the implementation and also added a link to a playground.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova No, unfortunately this had no effect. I've updated my question so now Item extends directly form the nested object without the need of another type.

Comment: Ugh, this is rough.  Could you look at [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND5ojm) and see if it meets your needs?  If not, please provide the use case it fails for.  If so, I can write up an answer, but this is a minefield of issues in any case.